# what is meant by "in an otherwise" in a sentence?

Tags: grammar, phrases

Here is the statement:  This is not a temporary rupture in an otherwise stable equilibrium: the crisis

through which we are living is a turning point in history.

Comment: _In an otherwise_ doesn't mean anything, as it is not a consituent of any sentence.

Answer (score 2):

We can use 'otherwise' as an adverb meaning "except for what has just been referred to". This is not a temporary rupture in an equilibrium which would be stable except for that (the rupture).

[Otherwise (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/otherwise)